# Windows 10 : Pen (stylus) not working on MFC application

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-10, stylus-pen

I have an MFC application that works fine with Pen ([Stylus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylus_(computing))) under Windows 7, but unfortunately, it does not work on Windows 10.

- Under **Windows 7**,  I am able to scroll vertically with the stylus WITHOUT using (*clicking and dragging*) the scroll bar, i can scroll vertically by clicking and dragging from anywhere in my dialog (formview)
- Under **Windows 10**, I am not able to scroll vertically with the stylus WITHOUT using (*clicking and dragging*) the scroll bar. I must click (and drag) with the Stylus on the scroll bar to scroll vertically

**My need :**
  I need to be able to scroll vertically with the stylus WITHOUT using (clicking and dragging) the scroll bar on Windows 10

**Detail:**
I am on Windows 10 with Visual studio 2010.

**My opinion**
I think that the version of **MFC100.dll** (related to my Visual Studio 2010) does probably not support the functionality of the stylus under Windows 10 because the code works correctly under windows 7

Someone has already encountered this problem ?
Thanks.

Comment: *"Any suggestions ?"* is not an answerable question.

Comment: @IInspectable suggestions, ideas, explanations, solution ...

Comment: To what problem? Please see [ask].

Comment: @IInspectable *I am not able to scroll vertically with the stylus WITHOUT using (clicking and dragging) the scroll bar on Windows 10*

Comment: Yes, great. What problem do you need solved? Do you want parity with Windows 7? If so, do you want to port Windows 10's behavior ported to Windows 7? The other way around? Something else altogether? Again, read [ask].

Comment: @IInspectable my problem is that **I am not able to scroll vertically with the stylus WITHOUT using (clicking and dragging) the scroll bar on Windows 10** so i need to **be able to scroll vertically with the stylus WITHOUT using (clicking and dragging) the scroll bar on Windows 10**

Comment: [Legacy Support for Panning with Scroll Bars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/legacy-support-for-panning-with-scrollbars).

Answer (score 0):

I post this answer to help people who are in the same situation as me.

**1. Introduction**

Interaction with the scrollbar can be can be done using (It’s probably not the only methods that exist):

- [SetScrollPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setscrollpos) coupled with [ScrollWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-scrollwindow). The first scrolls the bare scroll, the second scrolls the contents of the window
- [ScrollToPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/mfc/reference/cscrollview-class?view=vs-2019#cscrollviewscrolltoposition) which scrolls both the scroll bare and the contents of the window

The first method ([SetScrollPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setscrollpos) coupled with [ScrollWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-scrollwindow)) requires management of all scrollbar informations : scrollable size, current position, ... and recalculate it on each OnSize () (which is not too trivial ...)

With the seconde method ([ScrollToPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/mfc/reference/cscrollview-class?view=vs-2019#cscrollviewscrolltoposition)) mode, all we have to do is to call the `ScrollToPosition` with the desired scrolling size. We don't have to manage the details of the scroll bare, Windows does it for us!

For some reason that I don't know, the `stylus` scroll functionality on `Windows 10` does not have the same behavior on `Windows 7` : The scrollbar scrolls **but not the contents of the window** !!!

**2. Solution**

Having spent several hours on this problem, I conclude that the simple solution to work around this problem is to use the [ScrollToPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/mfc/reference/cscrollview-class?view=vs-2019#cscrollviewscrolltoposition) function as much as possible. And in this case, you just need to calculate scrolled size (`delta`) which is defined by:

- Starts when the mouse button is pressed (Stulys pointed) (use [ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/mfc/reference/wm-message-handlers-l-m?view=vs-2019))
- Extended/reduced during drag (use [ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/mfc/reference/wm-message-handlers-l-m?view=vs-2019))
- Ends when the button is released (use [ON_WM_LBUTTONUP](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/mfc/reference/wm-message-handlers-l-m?view=vs-2019))

All you have to do is call the `ScrollToPosition` function with the calculated `delta`. This will allow you to move from an extremely complicated management mode to a few things that look like this:

**ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN**

```
void CMyView::OnLButtonDown (UINT nFlags, CPoint point) 
{
    // Code here ...
    POINT p;
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    ScreenToClient ( &p); // Convert to screen coordinates

    m_dragPosition = p; // m_dragPosition : member variable to store click position
    m_bMouseDown = true; // Set Flag to true

    CWnd::OnLButtonDown (nFlags, point) ;
}
```

**ON_WM_LBUTTONUP**

```
void CMyView::OnLButtonUp (UINT nFlags, CPoint point) 
{
    // Code here ...  
    m_bMouseDown = false;
    CWnd::OnLButtonUp(nFlags, point);
}
```

**ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE**

```
void CMyView::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) 
{
   int delta = p.y - m_dragPosition.y;

   // Use absolute value to take into account top/bottom scrolling
   if ( abs (delta) > SCROLLING_STEP_SIZE)
   {
       CPoint pp = GetScrollPosition (); // Get current scrollbar position
       pp.y += -delta;
       pp.x = 0;  // I'm intersting only for vertical scrolling
       ScrollToPosition (pp);   // Scroll to new position
       UpdateWindow (); // This redraw new showed area
       m_dragPosition = p; // Update drag position
   }
}
```

By adding this, you avoid explicit management which is not at all trivial...
Hope this will help those who are in the same situation as me