# MFC: Touchscreen scrolling problem on Windows 10

Tags: c++, mfc, touchscreen, vertical-scrolling

I need to migrate a big Visual studio 2010 *MFC* project from **Windows 7** to **Windows 10**
My application is intended to be used on tablets with a ***touchscreen*** (the source of the problem and therefore the origin of this post)
I am doing some preliminary tests (Project [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4087/How-to-implement-a-scrollable-child-dialog)) to evaluate the feasibility of this migration and I already detect a bug in the MFC library : **Bad vertical scroll management when using touchscreen**

If i use the default vertical scroll function :

```
void CDlgScrollable::OnVScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
    CDialog::OnVScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
    return;
}
```

I get a bad scrolling result :

[image]

As you see, the scrollbar is at the end but the formview is at top.

**important notes:**

- I didn't have this problem on Windows 7
- This problem occurs only when using the **touchscreen**. if I use the mouse everything goes well.

I migrated my project from visual studio 2010 to visual studio 2017, thinking that it comes from an incompatibility between the old version of MFC 2010 (MFC100.dll) and Windows 10 but I still have the same problem on visual studio 2017

**Question:**

how can i fix this? although I think I have only two choices:

- Explicitly manage scrolling (which will be extremely complicated because I have a lot of dialogs with setfocus on controls ....)
- Wait for the Microsoft update ....

Comment: [Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62024461/1889329). With the [same answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/legacy-support-for-panning-with-scrollbars).

Comment: Thanks. that's what I feared the most, rewriting everything explicitly ...